# Updating a record if an hour has passed since being submitted

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

I know there are many questions like this but I cannot make them apply to my situation, I am having trouble working with time differences.

Iam using Code Igniter and I have a db that has rows of "jobs" in it with various fields, one being `submitted_time (of type TIME)` which is set to `date('H:i:s', time())` at the time of insertion and the other `service_response(of type TIME)`  which is `set manually to "02:00:00"` at insertion.

I am trying to write a function that when ran checks if an hour has passed since the post was added, but am having trouble understanding the best way to accomplish this.

Below is my attempt which was to convert all the strings from the two fields to a unix time stamp and echo out the "job" if the time submitted is greater than than the time now + 1 hour (service_response/2)

```
function updateJobTimes()
{
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    $oj = $this->job_model->getAllTodaysOpenJobs();
    //var_dump($oj);
    foreach($oj as $job) 
    {
        $timesubmitted = strtotime($job->submitted_time);
        $now = strtotime(date('H:i:s', time()));
        //responsetime = now + 1 hour;
        $responsetime = strtotime("+1 hours");

        echo "Submitted_time =" . $job->submitted_time. "<br>\r\n";
        echo "strtotime(Submitted_time) =". $timesubmitted. "<br>\r\n";
        echo "Service_reponse =" . $job->service_response. "<br>\r\n";
        echo "strtotime(Serivce_response) =" .$responsetime. "<br>\r\n";
        echo "Time now =".$now. "<br>";
        echo "response time(now +1hour) =". date('H:i:s', $responsetime) ."<br>";
        echo "-----just a separator---------------------------------- <br>";




        //this should show the last job "job#2105" which is the last iteration in the picture below 
        if($timesubmitted > $responsetime)
        {
            $difference = $res - $timesubmitted;
            echo "<p class='well'>Job #".$job->reference. "</p>\r\n";
        }
    }
}
```

But it is never or always meeting the condition.

I am genuinely at a loss and have read every question that turned up in google but they are either based around the time and date being in the same field or wanting to return a user readable string like "x Minutes ago" or they use a  sql select statement but I already have a statement that only pulls back jobs from the current day(above), I just want to list these jobs out if they have been submitted for more than an hour.

Sorry if the question it too long, too stupid or doesn't provide enough information(or too much), I am asking because I am lost.

**EDIT: Updated Method A with help of @ChrisG and added a picture to display the problem (that last job(#2105) shouldn't be there)**

**EDIT 2:Updated method again and update the picture to show what both variables are that are being checked.**

**EDIT 3: I have a feeling looking at my code that the condition will never be met because the submitted time will never be greater than whatever time it is now +1 hour since now will always change...I feel stupid just writing that out, but I cant seem to get it right the right if statement, I feel closer now than earlier but still lost. Maybe response time should be the submitted time + one hour? **

thank you for reading

The var dumps of the variables

[image]

Comment: Have you tried dumping all the timestamps out generated from strtotime() and comparing?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reading, Yes, I will update with a picture showing them, I didn't include them because I thought I was using the function incorrectly so they would have been irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, I have dumped them but since they're such large numbers I can't(read:me stupid) really verify them myself.

Comment: What are you trying to do here: $res = date("+2 hours"); - Are you trying to do $res = strtotime("+2 hours"); ?

Comment: That was another attempt to add 2 hours on to the current time so I could do if(submitted_time > $res) ($res supposed to = current time + 2 hours) - Sorry just seen your update, thats what I was trying to do, but obviously doing it wrong, I will try with that.

Comment: Try changing $res = date("+2 hours"); to strtotime("+2 hours") which will give you two hours ahead of the current time.  Wouldn't you want to do something more like strtotime("+2 hours",$submitted_time); which will give you two hours after the submitted time?  Then you can say if $res is greater than $submitted_time then it's been longer than two hours.  If the submitted time were 5am and its now 8am, if you just did strtotime("+2 Hours"); it wouldnt be 2 hours after 5am, it would be whatever now is +2 hours.

Comment: Why not simply store the time of creation in the record. Then when you use the record, or not, you can easily check its age against the current time.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the help, I thought that was what I needed at first but now it's echo'ing jobs out that aren't more than 2 hours old, for example I added a job just now to make sure its only echo'ing the correct jobs but its echo'ing the newly added one too.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the creation time is stored in the database as submitted_time, the problem is I am struggling using this to work out if a job was posted more than 2 hours ago from when the methods ran, thank you for your comment.

Comment: I would store an absolute time, not a time relative to the time of day. So not of mysql type `TIME` but of type `TIMEDATE`. That way you can always get an absolute time difference. Sorry, I cannot answer since you're using 'codeigniter', and I have no idea what that does.

Comment: Should strtotime('service response') be a constant?

Comment: Hi, No service_response is just another field in the database the idea at first being I can set the service response for each job with it and do (pseudo code) if($timesubmitted >= $timenow + service_response) then echo job etc
But I'll be happy just getting something manually set working then I can figure it out myself how to tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
function updateJobTimes()
{
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    $oj = $this->job_model->getAllTodaysOpenJobs();
    //var_dump($oj);
    foreach($oj as $job) 
    {
        $timesubmitted = strtotime($job->submitted_time);
        $now = strtotime(date('H:i:s', time()));

        $responsetime = strtotime("+1 hours", $timesubmitted);

        // echo "Submitted_time =" . $job->submitted_time. "<br>\r\n";
        // echo "strtotime(Submitted_time) =". $timesubmitted. "<br>\r\n";
        // echo "strtotime(Serivce_response) =" .$responsetime. "<br>\r\n";
        // echo "Time now =".$now. "<br>";
        // echo "response time(now +1hour) =". date('H:i:s', $responsetime) ."<br>";
        // echo "-----just a separator---------------------------------- <br>";





        if($now > $responsetime)
        {
            //$difference = $res - $timesubmitted;
            echo "<p class='well'>Job #".$job->reference. " was submitted at ".date('H:i:s',$timesubmitted). " and its response time is " .date('H:i:s',$responsetime). " and it is now ".date('H:i:s',time()). "</p>\r\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I was doing `if(the time submitted was greater than the time submitted + 1hour)` which will always be true what I should have been doing is `if(**thetimenow** is greater than time_submitted + 1 hour)` //which in my case should return all the results except 1, which it does, hope it helps anyone as confused as I was.

**Not really sure of the etiquette of accepting your own answer as the solution so i wont, but this does work for me and frankly probably already makes sense to most people, I just got caught up in the problem.**